# Entropy change relation to the number of lost bits

Tags: entropy

Can we use entropy change value to define the (perhaps fractional) number of
bits of information that are lost by and, or, xor gates?

Comment: "these entropy changes"
What entropy changes are you referring to?
My guess is you're referring to adiabatic, isothermal etc.
I don't see why energy entropy should be related to computing entropy so directly.

Also, you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)

Comment: I am sorry for that error

Comment: Possible duplicate: [v1](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/55046/revisions) of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55046/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I have simple logic gates(and, or, xor). I want to calculate the entropy change due to this gates. Say "or" gate. we have 2 inputs(2 bits 0 or 1) and 1 output. This gate is not reversible, if we know the output, we cannot guess the input bits. We have computed entropy somehow, how to find the number of lost bits

Comment: @Raindrop Surprisingly, the information and thermodynamic entropies associated with the erasure of the bit are deeply related: see Bennett's seminal work, the [Thermodynamics of Computation](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/computing/nano/documents/Bennett%20-%20The%20Thermodynamics%20Of%20Computation.pdf).

Comment: Sorry. I really don't have enough knowledge about this. Ignore what I said!

Comment: @Raindrop No need to apologise :) You should read the link though, it's awesome.